# Error C2676: std::set::const_iterator doesn't have operator+ function?

Tags: c++, iterator, operator-overloading, std, stdset

```
std::set<int> s = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
std::set<int> s2(s.begin(), s.begin() + 2);
```

I want to assgin several values of s into `s2`. But got below compile error:

> Error C2676   binary '`+`':
>   '`std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>>`'
>   does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to
>   the predefined

It seems `std::set::const_iterator` doesn't have `operator+` method.

Comment: Makes sense, since `std::set` doesn't support random access.

Comment: `std::set<T>::const_iterator` is a stock bi-directional iterator class. You can increment/decrement it's iterators, but not treat them as random-access.

Comment: you can use `std::next` to get the third iterator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems `std::set::const_iterator` doesn't have `operator+` method.

You are right about this.

Operations such as `s.begin() + 2` is only possible for *[random access iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator)* (see the **Expression** s in the link). 
But, [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) has only *[bidirectional iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator)* (both `std::set::iterator` and `std::set::const_iterator`).

---

However, you could use [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) to do this job in a generic way, which returns the `n`th successor of iterator which we pass.

```
#include <iterator>  // std::next

std::set<int> s2(s.begin(), std::next(s.begin(), 2));
// or const_iterator    
std::set<int> s3(s.cbegin(), std::next(s.cbegin(), 2));
```

Comment: @Zhang Alternatively, you could implement `operator+` for any iterators, using the `std::next` as follows. https://godbolt.org/z/TU4IiN. I am not aware of drawbacks(if any) of using it though.

Comment: @Zhang Well, I asked it here: [Is there any drawbacks in providing operator+ or operator- to bidirectional iterators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59573324/is-there-any-draw-backs-in-providing-operator-or-operator-to-bidirectional-ite)

Answer (score 2):

`set`s are usually implemented as a tree rather than a contiguous data store. With a tree you can only find a contained item from the proceeding item and have to iterate one at a time, making the + operator not very effective. As a result they only provide [Bi-Directional Iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator)).

To get an effective `operator+` you need a container that can provide [Random Access Iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator)