# How to iterate std::set based on offset from set.begin()?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, iterator, stdset

I need to get an iterator based on offset.

i.e. having the iterator for begin :

```
auto it = set.begin()
```

I need to get to the iterator having offset `ofst`:

```
it + ofst
```

Is there a way to do that? of I need incremental increase `it++` the iterator `ofst` times.

Comment: [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) but it basically has to increment n times for non contiguous containers such as `std::set`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to get to the iterator having offset `ofst`: `it + ofst`: is there
> a way to do that?

No, there is no `operator+` overload defined for this for `std::set::iterator` (aka *bidirectional iterators*). However, you can use  [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next), from [`<iterator>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iterator) header as follows to achive the same.

```
#include <iterator>  // std::next

auto nthIter = std::next(it, ofst);
```

This basically behind the scene increments `ofst` times too.

The `std::set` has [bidirectional iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator), which has no luxuries like [random access iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), and hence need to increment like this.

---

That being said, you could overload the `operator+`(and maybe `operator-`) for the bidirectional iterators, [which will not be recommended though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59573324/is-there-any-drawbacks-in-providing-operator-or-operator-to-bidirectional-iter/59573429#59573429).