# operator< overload for std::set::insert not working as expected

Tags: c++, set, operator-overloading

I am trying to implement a `std::set::insert` such that it will 'insert' a struct given that one does not already exist.

I have added the required custom operator overload for 'less than' (`<`); however, when the code is executed it just seems to skip past it and not work as expected. (Implementation for which was modified (addition of the `const noexcept` was taken from here: [C2676: binary '<': 'const _Ty' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61455321/c2676-binary-const-ty-does-not-define-this-operator-or-a-conversion-to))

Sample Code:

```
#include <set>

struct Coordinate
{
int x;
int y;

Coordinate(int x = 0, int y = 0) : x(x), y(y)
{
}

bool operator==(const Coordinate& obj)
{
    return x == obj.x && y == obj.y;
}

bool operator!=(const Coordinate& obj)
{
    return x != obj.x && y != obj.y;
}

bool operator< (const Coordinate& obj) const noexcept
{
    return x < obj.x && y < obj.y;
}
};

int main(){
std::set<Coordinate> current_set = {Coordinate(1, 2)};

Coordinate new_coordinate(1, 3);

current_set.insert(new_coordinate);
}
```

To be clear, with this implementation, the set does not get updated with the `new_coordinate` object even though the members clearly differ.

Any assistance on this would be appreciate.

Comment: Hi, so from what I have read it seems that it is at least sorted (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). I believe you can also use an unsorted_set for that too. Have you come across this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[std::set - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) says:

> In imprecise terms, two objects a and b are considered equivalent if neither compares less than the other: !comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a).

The member `x` of the two objects `Coordinate(1, 2)` and `Coordinate(1, 3)` are both 1, so `operator<` cannot be true and therefore they are considered as same.

Commonly-used implementation will be like this:

- `A < B` is true if `A.x < B.x`
- `A < B` is false (because `B < A` is true) if `A.X > B.x`
- When `A.x == B.x`, `A < B` iff `A.y < B.y`

```
bool operator< (const Coordinate& obj) const noexcept
{
    return x < obj.x || (x == obj.x && y < obj.y);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation of `operator<` is incorrect for the purpose of `std::set`. It does not meet the requirements of [strictly weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings).

Change it to:

```
bool operator<(const Coordinate& obj) const noexcept
{
    if ( x != obj.x )
    {
       return x < obj.x;
    }
    return y < obj.y;
}
```

You can simplify that by using [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie).

```
bool operator<(const Coordinate& obj) const noexcept
{
    return std::tie(x, y) < std::tie(obj.x, obj.y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement the other answers that explain the problem: Here is C++20 version of the class:

```
struct Coordinate
{
    int x;
    int y;
    
    friend auto
    operator<=>(const Coordinate&, const Coordinate&) = default;
};

int main()
{
    std::set<Coordinate> current_set = {{1, 2}};
    current_set.emplace(1, 3);
}
```